# how to get the value of a user_id link from html table using php

Tags: php, html

`$row[0]` is user_id when i click on user_id i need to know how to get the value i clicked from the html table using php so i can use this id to select its data into another form so i can edit it

```
$select = "SELECT U.id, U.first_name, U.last_name, U.email_address, U.password, U.gender, U.day, U.month, U.year, COUNT(O.user_id) FROM users U LEFT JOIN orders O ON U.id = O.user_id GROUP  BY U.id ORDER BY id $order LIMIT $offset , $rowsPerPage";    
$result=mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>

<table>
<tr>      
    <td><?php echo "<a href= 'editUser.html'> $row[0]</a>"; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[1];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[2];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[3];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[4];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[5];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[6];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[7];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[8];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[9];}
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass as query string and will be available in `$_GET`

```
<td><?php echo "<a href= 'editUser.html?id=".$row[0]."'> $row[0]</a>"; ?></td>
```

You can get in next page like this

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't "get" id from HTML table.
You can only send it using a hyperlink

```
$select = "SELECT U.id, U.first_name, U.last_name, U.email_address, U.password, U.gender, U.day, U.month, U.year, COUNT(O.user_id) FROM users U LEFT JOIN orders O ON U.id = O.user_id GROUP  BY U.id ORDER BY id $order LIMIT $offset , $rowsPerPage";    
$result=mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
  $data[] = $row;
}
?>

<table>
  <tr>
<? foreach($data as $row) { ?>
    <td><a href="edituser.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['id']?></a></td>
<? } ?>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use Ajax request to send data from table to server.